# Recursive function returns undefined when there is only one numerical possibility

Tags: javascript, recursion

The code below contains a recursive method which should always return 7 however it return undefined whenever it has to re-generate a number because the number generated was already contained within the array that is defined at the top of the code.

My question is... why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
var id = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

function generatePlayerId(){
  var check = false;
  var tempId = Math.floor(Math.random()*7)+1;
  for(var i=0;i<id.length;i++){
    if(tempId == id[i]){
      check = true;
    }
  }
  if(check){
    console.log(tempId);
    generatePlayerId();
  }else{
    console.log(tempId);
    return tempId;
  }
}

var num = generatePlayerId();

console.log(num);
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just get the last item in the array and increment it?

Comment: @Jesse kernaghan well I could except that the array doesn't necessarily need to be in ascending order.

Comment: "*…should always return 7*" - then why are you doing something random?

Comment: In addition to what the others already commented/answered: Instead of traversing the array you could simply use [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), also your function would be more reusalbe if you'd pass in the used ids instead of using a global var.

Comment: @ChristopherBell you could sort the array first, or do you mean that you aren't necessarily looking for the next highest from the set? Recursively attempting to hit a random number and then looping an array to see if it exists seems overcomplicated to say the least, but perhaps I'm missing a key part of the question.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan  I was fairly vague in my question. That was my mistake however thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the recursive case, you'll want to return as well. This will enable the base case to return the value that was generated through all the recursive calls that came before.

Try this:

```
var id = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

function generatePlayerId(){
  var check = false;
  var tempId = Math.floor(Math.random()*7)+1;
  for(var i=0;i<id.length;i++){
    if(tempId == id[i]){
      check = true;
    }
  }
  if(check){
    console.log(tempId);
    return generatePlayerId();
  }else{
    console.log(tempId);
    return tempId;
  }
}

var num = generatePlayerId();

console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 2):

> why is this happening

in that `if (check)` branch nothing is `return`ed, so you'll get back `undefined`.

> how can I fix it?

Just return the result of the recursive call:

```
…
console.log(tempId);
if (check)
  return generatePlayerId();
//^^^^^^
else
  return tempId;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes complete sense.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that you need to return the result of the recursive call, not just make the recursive call.

There is a major problem with this approach, however: there is a non-zero chance of overflowing the stack because there is no limit to the recursion. You'd be much better off converting this to an iterative algorithm (which may run for an arbitrary amount of time, for the same reason, but will at least not gobble up more and more memory as it runs). You also don't need to write your own code to search the array; use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Something like this should work:

```
function generatePlayerId(){
    var tempId;
    do{
        tempId = Math.floor(Math.random()*7)+1;
    } while (id.indexOf(tempId) !== -1);
    return tempId;
}
```

Also, this will probably be much faster than a recursive algorithm.